# Is EPPlus.Core Safe?

Tags: deployment, epplus

I decided to use EPPlus.Core to create excel documents on my .Net Core API project. I have just realised that if I click the "EPPlus library" url on the following web site Google gives a critical warning.

https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core

[image]

And I see this message on the Show Details section:

"Warnings are shown for websites where harmful software has been detected. You can check the status of “archive.codeplex.com” on the Google Safe Browsing diagnostic page."

So is EPPlus.Core safe? Does it steal info from server? Anyone currently using it had any issues?

Comment: Thats  an odd warning as the URL is gihub.com.  Are you somehow being redirected by your network?  Epplus.core is actually archived sine the main Epplus library works with .net core so you are better using that anyway:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: There is a description in the GitHub url saying that "EPPlus.Core is an unofficial port of the EPPlus library to .NET Core." and I see this error when I click the "EPPlus library" url. There is no network setup at my home.

Comment: Ahh...you mean the link to codeplex.  Codeplex was retried by Microsoft when they bought GitHub.  Not sure why codeplex is flagged like that.  But anything you use should come from Github anyway.  I am sure it is safe but unless there is a specific reason you should use the office Epplus since it would have the latest fixes.